# Message if Path dont exists in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, path

Is there a way to check if the path exists and if not to show an Message that the Path doesnt 
exist in C#  ? I tryed already if and else methods but not working btw i really searched  hard on Google before asking :P

```
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
            MessageBox.Show("FAIL");
        {

            else if  ;Process.Start(path);
```

Comment: Please post exactly what you have tried that is not working.

Comment: [File.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Directory.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: you haven't done your homework I guess..

Comment: Please go back and edit that sample code - what you posted is garbage and could not possibly compile.

Comment: First of all, that code you posted won't even compile. Second (assuming you have code that actually compiles), did you try debugging, to see what value is in the variable `path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!File.Exist(path to file))
 {
   MessageBox.Show("File Not Found");
 }
 else
  //process code here
```

also need to add the using System.IO namespace

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Process.Start(path);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Fail");
}
```

Comment: then there must be a problem with your 'path' string.

Comment: @HassanBrate Don't just say "not functioning". That's like telling a doctor "it hurts" and saying absolutely nothing else. What is the error? What happens?

Comment: @user3684526 Directory.Exists is not going to tell you if the *file* exists.

Comment: Directory.Exists is telling you if a directory exists you need to use File.Exists hence the words in the code.